# Animate a sphere following the path of spline curve in 3D

Tags: graphics3d, animation

Instead of a point, I want to animate a 3D Sphere to following the path of this 3D-spline. How would I do this with the given code below. Any solutions to this ?

```
 pts = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0.5, 1.5, 1}}; 
 s = BSplineFunction[pts, SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> 1];
 Animate[
   ParametricPlot3D[s[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
     Epilog :> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[s[t]]}], 
  {t, 0., 1.}]
```

Comment: 1. You should use a different dummy variable for `ParametricPlot3D[]` and `Animate[]` 2. `Epilog` is only intended for appending 2D primitives. Thus: `Animate[Show[ParametricPlot3D[s[t], {t, 0, 1}], Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[s[u]]}]], {u, 0., 1.}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put 3D graphics objects in a epilog clause. `The Epilog` option is strictly for adding a 2D foreground to a plot, 2D or 3D. You should use `Show` and make the sphere with a `Graphics` expression. Like so.

```
pts = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0.5, 1.5, 1}};
s = BSplineFunction[pts, SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> 1];

Animate[
  Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[s[t], {t, 0, 1}],
    Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[s[t], Scaled[.02]]}]],
  {t, 0., 1}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful

Comment: @BrandonM. Helpful but not worth an up-vote?

Comment: How do I do that? I'm new to stackexchange.

Comment: @BrandonM. Just click on the up-arrow on lefthand side of the answer -- above the acceptance checkmark that you have already clicked on (and thanks for that).

Answer (score 1):

```
Animate[ParametricPlot3D[s[t], {t, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
   Mesh -> {{u}}, MeshStyle -> Red] /. Point[x_] :> Sphere[x, .05], {u,  0., 1.}]
```

[image]